# how to add +3 in date('H:i:s')?

Tags: php, mysql

i need to add 3 hours or after 3 hours (GMT+3) in  date('H:i:s') in my query

```
$query2="SELECT location FROM course where Dr_ID = 2 AND time_start <= '".date('H:i:s')."' and time_end > '".date('H:i:s')."'";
```

and thanks

Comment: What type `time_start` field is?

Comment: @zerkms: your solution is the same one that I would have given...why'd you delete it?

Comment: @Mark: because I've forgotten about `time` type in mysql :-S

Comment: @zerkms: he already had the right format though ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can acheive that by using time() function and then adding the number of seconds to adjust the DateTime variable.

In this case, you want to add 3 hours, which is

```
  3 Hours = 60 Seconds X 60 Minutes X 3
```

so,  `time() + (3*60*60)` will do the job

here is the updated query

```
    $query2="SELECT location FROM course 
   where Dr_ID = 2 
   AND time_start <= '".date('H:i:s')."' 
   and time_end > '".date('H:i:s',time()+(3*60*60))."'";
```

Answer (score 1):

`date("H-i-s", mktime(date('H')+3, date('i'), date('s'), 0, 0, 0));`

Answer (score 1):

You can try `date("h:i:s" ,strtotime("+3 hours"));`

This should help you out